Style Props of Button component doesn't apply in screen.debug
Im kinda new with the React Testing library. But I'm having a strange issue found during testing. Here's is my setup and code.
on  ../testUtils/rtl
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { render, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import extendedTheme from '@/styles/themes';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

const Providers: React.FC<{children: ReactNode}> = ({ children }) => (
  <ChakraProvider theme={extendedTheme}>{children}</ChakraProvider>
);

const customRender = (
  ui: React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>>,
  options?: RenderOptions
) => {
  return render(ui, { wrapper: Providers, ...options });
};

export * from '@testing-library/react';
export { customRender as render };

on the test suites:
import { render } from '../../testUtils/rtl';
import {Button } from '@chakra-ui/react';

describe('Button', () => {
 
    it('sample test style props button', () => {
        
    
        const { container } = render(
            <Button backgroundColor={'red'}> sample red box</Button>
        );

        screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL();

        const containerDiv = window.getComputedStyle(container);

        expect(containerDiv.backgroundColor).toBe('red');
    });

Result in log testing playground:

The console output:
● Button › sample test style props button
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "red"
Received: ""

  40 |         const containerDiv = window.getComputedStyle(container);
  41 |
> 42 |         expect(containerDiv.backgroundColor).toBe('red');
     |                                              ^
  43 |     });
  44 |

Do I miss something on my setup. I would appreciate any help or insight regarding this.
I'm expecting to see a red button on the screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL().

Use screen .getByRole to select the button and apply getComputedStyle directly on the button element.
import { render, screen } from '../../testUtils/rtl';
import { Button } from '@chakra-ui/react';

describe('Button', () => {
  it('sample test style props button', () => {
    render(<Button backgroundColor="red">sample red box</Button>);
    screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL();

    const buttonElement = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /sample red box/i });
    const buttonStyles = window.getComputedStyle(buttonElement);

    expect(buttonStyles.backgroundColor).toBe('red');
  });
});


it did pass on my test case. however, it didn't reflect on my logTestingPlaygroundURL. :c
also when I've tried to put a variant like this. it didn't apply the styles from theme.
  <Button
                data-testid="primary-btn"
                variant="primary"
            >
                This is primary variant
            </Button>


